# upgrade ios 9 to 10 february 2019

Tags: ios, itunes

I have a 6 plus. I have left ios 9.something there.
If I want to update right now, as of right now the ios 12 is availble but i must install it from itunes.

[image]

Can I downlaod 10.0 on itunes and upgrade my 9.x to 10.x manually
SO I dont have to install  12x